# Shouldn't there be a || instead of && here?

Tags: javascript

The code works great and all but I'm just confused as to why there is an AND statement instead of an OR. Both the conditions shouldn't have to equal true... only one.

```js
var apple = prompt("we there?");
while (apple !== "yes" && apple !== "yeah") {
  var apple = prompt("we thereeee?");

  alert("welcome here");
```

Comment: Please note that your code seems to be missing a closing brace ) `}` ) somewhere.

Comment: In simple words, if apple is not yeah AND apple is not yes, ask him again.

Comment: Read about De Morgan's laws, you may understand such type of conditional logic pretty well.

Answer (score 4):

No this condition means if the value of apple isn't yes or yeah then the statement should run.  as the condition is `!== (not equal)`

so if it is anything other than yes or yeah then the condition is true.

on the other hand if there was a or condition then it would mean if apple wasn't yes or wasn't yeah then the condition is true. but think of it this way  although the value of apple is not `yes` (thus the first part is true ) it's value stil can be yeah which is not expected here

Answer (score 2):

In your text you are describing the negation of the condition that is in the `while` loop. The condition in the while loop is expressing what is not valid, while your text is saying what is valid. The while loop's condition is saying "while it is **not** valid: get new input"

In boolean logic the [negation of a disjunction (an OR) is the conjunction (AND) of the negations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws).

So the `while` condition can also be written as follows:

```
while ( !(apple === "yes" || apple == "yeah") ) {
```

...which corresponds to what you are describing, but is equivalent. Note the additional negation `!` (NOT) and the negated comparisons (`===`).

Answer (score 1):

That's the thumb rule question... if there is a not equal to check then using OR means that one of the conditions will always be true ... so we need AND and not OR for NOT EQUAL TO checks with more than one condition...  ALWAYS :)